# VB6/VBA: How to write xml file in UTF-8 with BOM

Tags: xml, vba, encoding, vb6

I'm currently bugfixing legacy code written in VBA (not by me) and I need to save a XML file to disk in UTF-8 encoding (not a problem), but with the BOM (Byte Order Mark) included (problem).

The current code saving the DOM document to disk looks like this:

```
Private Sub mSaveToFile(ByVal oDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, ByVal sFilename As String)
    Dim oStream As ADODB.Stream
    Dim oWriter As MSXML2.MXXMLWriter60
    Dim oReader As MSXML2.SAXXMLReader60

    Set oStream = New ADODB.Stream
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = adTypeBinary

    Set oWriter = New MSXML2.MXXMLWriter60
    'if not set (even to False), ".encoding" is ignored
    oWriter.byteOrderMark = True
    oWriter.output = oStream
    oWriter.indent = True
    oWriter.standalone = True
    oWriter.omitXMLDeclaration = False
    'UTF-8 will never write a BOM, no matter what ".byteOrderMark" says
    oWriter.Encoding = "utf-8"



    Set oReader = New MSXML2.SAXXMLReader60
    Set oReader.contentHandler = oWriter
    Set oReader.dtdHandler = oWriter
    Set oReader.ErrorHandler = oWriter

    Call oReader.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", oWriter)
    Call oReader.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", oWriter)

    Call oReader.parse(oDoc.xml)

    Call oStream.SaveToFile(sFilename, adSaveCreateOverWrite)
    oStream.Close

End Sub
```

I do not completely understand what it's doing, but it's doing its job.

The included comments are the digest of what I found out online, that Microsoft doesn't care, what the developer wants (.byteOrderMark = True) and doesn't write any BOM (at least not with UTF-8).
I even found online, that it is **not** recommended to use a BOM with UTF-8, but what can one do when it is a requirement.

So, now I'm looking for a way to write the BOM myself, but I can't find a way to use "oWriter" or "oReader" to write random bytes to the stream.

Am I missing something important here, or is it simply not possible to create UTF-8 files with BOM with Microsoft XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I overlooked that there is the "oStream" variable as well.

Just creating a byte array, inserting the BOM bytes into it and writing it to the stream did the trick.

```
...
Dim bom(3) As Byte

bom(1) = 239   'EF
bom(2) = 187   'BB
bom(3) = 191   'BF

Call oStream.Write(bom)
...
```